# Delete an object from Core Data Model and update Table

Tags: uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, delete-row, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a TableViewController (`favTable.m`) and with the help of `NSFetchedResultsController` it is filled with data extracted from a Core Data Model (1 entity with 2 attributes). I have included a delete button in the navigation bar, that when clicked it is supposed to delete the selected row of the table, as well as the respective object in the core data model. I am using the code below for the delete button but it returns error `[favTable delItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. What should I fix?

```
UIBarButtonItem *delButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Del"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self
                                                             action:@selector(delItem)];

- (void)delItem:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.managedObjectContext = ((ecoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;

    FavoritesInfo*favoritesInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:favoritesInfo];

    NSError *error= nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: How are you calling this method? If this is the direct action of a button it would need to be an IBaction instead of a void method.

Comment: Its a UIBarButton designed programmatically. @JayVersluis

Comment: Your method's signature is: `delItem:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, not just `delItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the exception because your method's signature is: `delItem:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, not just `delItem`.

In your case, I don't think you need neither `tableView` not `indexPath` to be parameters.

Instead, declare your tableView as a property (IBOutlet as well if done from storyboard).

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Then you have access to it using `self.tableView`.

As for the selected row, you can use `indexPathForSelectedRow`:

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
```

Now you can rewrite your UIButton's action to:

```
- (void) deleteSelectedItem {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    //Delete the item using your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you answering. I tried your suggestions but I get this error: Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:1037
 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Well anyway this error is not relevant to your answer most likely. You solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: You get that error because when you add/delete a cell, the data source doesn't reflect it. Post a different question if you can't solve it.